# ansible get the last character of a fact

Tags: python, string, ansible, slice

I would like to have the last character of a fact. My playbook looks like this:

```
- name: sf
  set_fact:
    root_dev: "{{ ansible_mounts|json_query('[?mount == `/`].device') }}"

- name: e
  debug:
    msg: "{{ root_dev[:-1] }}"
```

The problem is the output in this case always:

```
"msg": []
```

or if I use the playbook without semicolon:

```
  debug:
    msg: "{{ root_dev[-1] }}"
```

then the whole partition will be the output:

```
"msg": "/dev/sda1"
```

I also can't quote the whole `root_dev` because it is a fact and I would like to get the last character of it's value. The `split` filter also not working in this case, because the device can be `/dev/sda` or `/dev/mapper/root_part_0` and so. What would be the best option in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Explanation of the problem:

You have to understand how the [slicing works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/how-slicing-in-python-works). Given the lists *l1* and *l2* for testing

```yaml
  l1: [a]
  l2: [a, b, c]
```

The index [-1] gives you the last item (which is also the first item)

```yaml
  l1[-1]: a
```

The slice [:-1] gives you all items but the last one. The result is an empty list because there is only one item

```yaml
l1[:-1]: []
```

Test it by slicing *l2*

```yaml
 l2[:-1]: [a, b]
```

---

Solution:

The value of *root_dev* is a list

```yaml
  root_dev: "{{ ansible_mounts | json_query('[?mount == `/`].device') }}"
```

In your case

```yaml
  root_dev: ['/dev/sda1']
```

To get the number of the partition, index the first item in the list and the last character in the item

```yaml
  root_dev[0][-1]: 1
```

---

- Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    root_dev: "{{ ansible_mounts | json_query('[?mount == `/`].device') }}"

  tasks:

    - setup:
        gather_subset: mounts
    # - debug:
    #     var: ansible_mounts

    - debug:
        var: root_dev
    - debug:
        var: root_dev[0][-1]
```

---

- The above solution works for a single-digit partitions only. Use *regex_replace* to cover also multiple-digit options

```yaml
  part_no: "{{ root_dev.0 | regex_replace('^(.+?)(\\d*)$', '\\2') }}"
```

Answer (score 3):

It's more about Python slicing, not Ansible:

```yaml
- set_fact:
    root_dev: "/dev/sda1"

- debug:
    msg: "{{ root_dev[-1::] }}"
```

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "1"
}
```

See https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#slice for details.

EDIT: There is actually an issue with the query itself.

As you've mentioned in the comments, your initial query gives a list, and having `root_dev: "{{ ansible_mounts|json_query('[?mount == /].device') | join }}"` instead gives a string.

My suggestion, however, would be to use the built-in Jinja2 filters instead of `json_query` that [requires `jmespath` to be installed separately](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/json_query_filter.html#id2):

```yaml
- set_fact:
    root_dev: "{{ (ansible_mounts | selectattr('mount', 'equalto', '/') | first).device }}"
```

Comment: This also outputs me: `"msg": [ "/dev/sda1" ]`

Comment: Ok, I found what was the problem. `root_dev: "{{ ansible_mounts|json_query('[?mount == `/`].device') }}"` gave me back a list, not a string. After I modified it to: `root_dev: "{{ ansible_mounts|json_query('[?mount == `/`].device') | join }}"` so I made a string, your solution worked. Pls edit your answer based on this then I will accept it.

Comment: Yep, I just tested your query and found the same. But I have an alternative solution that doesn't require external libraries. I've edited my answer.

Comment: @AlexanderPletnev any drawback to doing the filter like this? `boot_dev: "{{ (ansible_mounts|selectattr('mount', 'equalto', '/boot')|list)[0].device }}"`.  I had something similar in a playbook already. Still learning Jinja

Comment: @Squashman not that I'm aware of, I just prefer the things to be as declarative as possible. CORRECTION: `selectattr` already returns a list so there's no point in applying `list` filter again.

Comment: @AlexanderPletnev that’s a legacy habit of some seasoned Ansible dev that has an hard time dying. In fact, in older version of Jinja, the generator returned by filters like `selectattr` was not automatically casted into a list, forcing you to use the `list` filter.